# Как смещать картинку внутри элемента при наведении на нее или элемент?

Tags: jquery, html5, css3

Есть HTML код:

```
<div class="articleBlock">
    <img src="wall/bobber-kong.jpg">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.articleBlock {
    background: white;
    border-radius: 10px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 60px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    height: 300px;
    margin-top: 5%;
    margin-left: 10%;
    margin-bottom: 5%;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    width: 80%;
}

.articleBlock img {
    position: absolute;
    top: -100px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Как с помощью jquery сделать так чтобы при наведении на элемент картинка сдвигалась в лево на 66%?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На jquery

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.articleBlock').on('mouseenter', function() {
    $('img', this).stop().animate({
      left: '66%'
    }, 500);
  }).on('mouseleave', function() {
    $('img', this).stop().animate({
      left: '0'
    }, 500);
  });
});
```

```css
.articleBlock {
  background: white;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 60px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  height: 300px;
  margin-top: 5%;
  margin-left: 10%;
  margin-bottom: 5%;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  width: 80%;
}
.articleBlock img {
  position: absolute;
  top: -100px;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="articleBlock">
  <img src="http://www.untitledmotorcycles.com/wp-content/gallery/bobber-kong_1/bobber-kong05.jpg">
</div>
```

На CSS3

```css
.articleBlock {
  background: white;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 60px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  height: 300px;
  margin-top: 5%;
  margin-left: 10%;
  margin-bottom: 5%;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  width: 80%;
}
.articleBlock img {
  position: absolute;
  top: -100px;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  -webkit-transition: left 500ms linear;
  -moz-transition: left 500ms linear;
  -o-transition: left 500ms linear;
  transition: left 500ms linear;
}
.articleBlock:hover img {
  left: 66%;
}
```

```html
<div class="articleBlock">
  <img src="http://www.untitledmotorcycles.com/wp-content/gallery/bobber-kong_1/bobber-kong05.jpg">
</div>
```

Comment: Отлично. Спасибо Вам

Comment: небольшой update сделал. добавил `.stop()`. это для того чтобы, если пользователь будет истерично мышкой туда сюда дергать